# Lunar vim does not highlight syntax error on solidity, the default LSP does not show

Tags: lua, solidity, neovim, language-server-protocol, lunarvim

When I was coding on solidity the syntax erros did not appear, every time I need to compile to solve see compilation problems.

I tried to download several plugins to Lunar VIM, tried to add vscode plugins too but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve this by install global `nomicfoundation-solidity-language-server` and change `config.lua` solidity LSP.

Install nomicfoundation-solidity-language-server globally

```
npm install @nomicfoundation/solidity-language-server -g
```

Change config.lua

```
local lspconfig = require 'lspconfig'
local configs = require 'lspconfig.configs'

configs.solidity = {
 default_config = {
 cmd = {'nomicfoundation-solidity-language-server', '--stdio'},
 filetypes = { 'solidity' },
 root_dir = lspconfig.util.find_git_ancestor,
 single_file_support = true,
 },
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working. Are you sure this is in line with the [docs](https://www.lunarvim.org/docs/configuration/language-features/language-servers)?

Answer (score 0):

For people using Mason, you can do :Mason and find the 'nomicfoundation-solidity-language-server' under the LSP tab and "I" for install. Should work out of the box.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35741242)